# Неправильная кодировка у тегов в чате

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация

В чате у тегов неправильная кодировка.
Вместо тегов [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33351/discussion-on-answer-by-stack-----c) выводятся ????? -- видно на скриншоте.
Это как-то можно исправить?

Сервер возвращает следующее:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
<a class="tag"
      href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f/info">??????</a> ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ага, проблема старая, но никак не решается (